# Any concrete survey on infinite and finite injury method?

Tags: reference-request, computability-theory, big-picture

I hope to have a historic outline of infinite and finite injury method and their main technical introdution.Any concrete survey on infinite and finite injury method recommended?

Comment: I would suggest Soare's book.